# Store a char value on an int using bitwise and keep value sign value correct when getting it back without a cast

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I have some `signed 8 bit` values that I want to store on a `signed 32 bit integer`.

I do that moving the values using bitwise shift left:

```
const auto value1 = char{90};
const auto value2 = char{80};
const auto value3 = char{70};
const auto value4 = char{60};

auto merged_value = int32_t{0};
merged_value |= (value1 & 0x000000FF) << 24;
merged_value |= (value1 & 0x000000FF) << 16;
merged_value |= (value1 & 0x000000FF) << 8;
merged_value |= value1 & 0x000000FF;
```

Now, let's say I want to get back `value1` from `merged_value` I will do that like this:

```
const auto back_value1 = (merged_value >> 24) & 0x000000FF;
```

This works great as long as `value1` is a positive number, but if the value is negative, the return value will be wrong.

For example, if `value1` is `-80`, then `back_value1` will be `176`, that's because the most significant bit (the positive or negative bit) is in bit position `7` and not in `31` (since `back_value1` is an `int32_t`).

Now, I know that I just need to do a cast to `char` on `back_value1` and I will get the `-80` value back. But what I want is a bitwise operation(s) that will give me the correct value `-80` to `back_value1` when `back_value1` is an `int32_t` and without a cast to `char`.

Thanks

Edit:

*Neil Butterworth* asked that I post the entire code here instead of on an online IDE, so here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
  const auto value = char{-80};
  std::cout << "value: " << (int)value << std::endl;

  std::cout << "value bits: " << std::bitset<32>(value) << std::endl;

  auto merged_value = uint32_t{0};
  merged_value |= (value & 0x000000FF) << 24;

  const auto back_value = int32_t(merged_value >> 24) & 0xFF;

  std::cout << "value: " << back_value << std::endl;
  std::cout << "back_value bits: " << std::bitset<32>(back_value) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: " I want to store on a signed 32 bit integer." - Why has it got to be signed?

Comment: It doesn't, can be a unsigned 32 bit too, since it acts just as a container in the end, I just put signed to be more specific, but I guess it just created confusion.

Comment: This looks like another example of where using the correct explicit types rather than `auto` would have solved the problem, or at least simplified it.

Comment: `char` can be unsigned. If you want a signed char, say so.

Comment: "I've added a example of my code in repl.it in this link." - please don't do that. Post all the code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that to get the value back as an `int32_t` with the same sign as the original `int8_t`, you need to either:

cast back to a `int8_t`:

```
const auto back_value1 = int32_t(int8_t((merged_value >> 24) & 0xFF));
```

or make sure the byte you need is at the left end of the `int32_t` before right shifting:

```
const auto back_value1 = merged_value /* << 0 */ >> 24;
const auto back_value2 = merged_value << 8 >> 24;
```

Needless to say, I don't recommend the latter.